# use newline as collapse parameter in paste and store result via lapply

Tags: r, parsing, paste

basically I have a bunch of text documents that have been read in via `readLines`. I then want to collapse each element as a new line of a document. The `paste(files,collapse=" ")` can dot his but `spaces` are used.

Unfortunately using:

```
parsed <- lapply(files, function(x) paste(x,collapse="\n"))
```

embeds a literal `\n` in the collapsed document. So the collapse parameter will not except special characters such as newline, tab and so on. It is entirely hard coded.

However using cat gets rid of this behaviour:

```
parsed <- lapply(files, function(x) cat(paste(x,collapse="\n")))
```

but the output is sent to the console (ie. all files). The output is correct but it is not being stored in `files`

Have I missed something, or does the nature of `cat` not lend itself to storing output into variables?

Comment: There's not a literal "`\n`" in your string, that's just how R prints new lines to the console. Do not use `cat` in the `lapply` function. You can use it on `cat(parsed)` after the fact if you want to print the new lines as new lines.

Comment: thanks very much. I also had to `unlist(parsed)` to pass into `cat`

Comment: Then you might want to be using `sapply()` rather than `lapply()`